# ChatGPT - Upload file via API (PHP)

Tags: php, openai-api

Trying to upload a jsonl file to chatgpt, for using it on my fine tuning.

But it returns error: "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Whats wrong with my codes, and how can I fix this?
Im trying to use "fine tuning" api. And to do it, first i need to upload a training file?

Here's my code:

```
<?php


$openAISecretKey = "";
$endpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/files';

$filePath = 'chatgpt.jsonl';

$size = filesize($filePath);
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);

$data = array(
    'file' => $fileContent,
    'purpose' => 'fine_tuning'
);

$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $openAISecretKey
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($response, true);

if ($result['object'] === 'file') {
    echo $result['id'];
} else {
    echo $result['error']['message'];
}
```

And my chatgpt.jsonl file is like:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a textile translater"
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Sample text"
        },
        {
            "role": "assistant",
            "content": "Sample response"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a textile translater"
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Sample text"
        },
        {
            "role": "assistant",
            "content": "Sample response"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a textile translater"
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Sample text"
        },
        {
            "role": "assistant",
            "content": "Sample response"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You state `"upload a jsonl file"` - but you are not uploading a file, merely the contents of a file. If the OpenAI endpoint is expecting a file then send a file, not text! According [to this documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/preparing-your-dataset) that is exactly what you need to do - so use [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) to add a file to your curl request